# Clicks in ListView Kotlin in the Android

Tags: android, kotlin, oncreate

I have do in Kotlin a 'listView' that present a name (questoes) and a position of list. I need when clicking in first position  ou second position go to another layout (position 0 for layout 'activity_e_ex1_port' and position 1 for layout 'activity_e_ex2_port'). But i have a bug in function 'onCreate' in the comands 'onCreate' and 'setContentView' in the struture 'if'.

```
    package com.example.asus.aprendecomigovelhinho

    import android.content.Context
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter
    import android.widget.ListView
    import android.widget.TextView
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_d_lista.*

    class D_lista : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_d_lista)

            val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView_CaixaEntrada)

            listView.adapter=MyCustomAdpter(this)
        }


        private class MyCustomAdpter(context: Context): BaseAdapter(){

            private val mContext: Context

            private val questoes = arrayListOf<String>(
                    "Português 1º ano", "Português 2º ano")

            init {
                mContext = context
            }

            //indicará quantas linhas terá a lista
            override fun getCount(): Int {
                return questoes.size
            }

            override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
                return position.toLong()
            }

            override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
                return "TEST STRING"
            }

            //para renderizar cada linha e depois a próxima
            override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                val rowlista = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_d_lista_row, viewGroup, false)

                val questaoTextView = rowlista.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewQuestão)
                questaoTextView.text = questoes.get(position )

                val ordem = position+1
                val positionTextView = rowlista.findViewById<TextView>                        (R.id.textViewPosicao)
                positionTextView.text = "Ordem de chegada: $ordem"

                return rowlista
            }

            fun onCreate(position: Int, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
                if(position==0) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_e_ex1_port)
                }

                if(position==1) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_e_ex2_port)
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should be using a RecyclerView instead

Comment: This mode not will work? It really does work with only RecyclerView?

Comment: No, it totally can work, but you're already making 2 major mistakes in your `getView()` implementation so you should probably use a RecyclerView instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `RecyclerView` where you can override `getItemViewType()` to use different layout in different positions.
For creating a `RecyclerView` refer [this](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-adapter-kotlin/) and for `getItemViewType()` refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)